# Proving a collection of subsets is a basis

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am given this definition of a basis:

Let $a$ be a point in a metric space $X$. A collection, $\mathfrak{B}_a$, of neighborhoods of $a$ is called a basis for the neighborhood system at $a$ if every neighborhood $N$ of $a$ contains some element $B \in \mathfrak{B}_a$.

Then, immediately, I am given some questions about proving whether or not these things are a basis.

It says, let $a$ be a point on the real line $R$. Prove all of the following constitute bases for the neighborhood system of $a$.

a. All closed intervals of the form $[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$, $\epsilon>0$

I'm not really sure how to go about proving this. From the definition, I feel like this is completely trivial. Won't ANY neighborhood, as in, the entire number line, contain some element of this interval? So, it is clearly a basis by choosing the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$?

b. All open balls $B(a;\frac{1}{n})$, $n$ is a positive integer.

Again, can I not just choose a neighborhood $B(a;1)$? Since $1/n \leq 1$ for any positive $n$?

If anyone knows of the typical method for going about proving a collection of subsets is a basis, I would greatly appreciate any pointers, because I feel kind of in the dark on this..

It then says,

Show that no finite collection of subsets on $R$ can be a basis for the system of neighborhoods at $a$. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to show that every neighborhood of $a$ contains some element of $\mathfrak{B}_a$, not that every element of $\mathfrak{B}_a$ is contained in some neighborhood of $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the definition, to prove that $\mathfrak{B}_a$ is a basis for the neighborhood system of $a$, you must prove that for any neighborhood $N$ of $a$, you can find an element of $B \in \mathfrak{B}_a$ such that $B \subseteq N$.  Note that you don't get to choose what $N$ is, the proof has to work for all possible neighborhoods $N$.

For example, to prove (a) is a basis for the neighborhood system at $a$, you would need to show that for an arbitrary neighborhood $N$ of $a$, there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that $[a−\epsilon,a+\epsilon] \subseteq N$.  Hint:

> Any neighborhood $N$ of $a$ must contain some open interval $(a-\epsilon_1, a+\epsilon_2)$.

The proof for (b) is very similar to the proof for (a).

For the second problem, start with an arbitrary finite collection of neighborhoods $\mathfrak{B}_a$, and show that there exists a neighborhood $N$ that does not contain any member of the collection.  Hint:

> Consider $\bigcap\mathfrak{B}_a$.